# Incompatible pointer types returning 'UITableViewCell *__strong' from a function with result type 'UITableView *' when try to view records

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, uitableview

I am loading the `SELECT` Query results in a `tableView` in the following manner but I am getting a warning that complains about incompatible pointer types.

What is the mistake in my code below?

Thanks for your suggestions in Advance

```
-(UITableView *)tableview : (UITableView *)tableview cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableview dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) 
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyleDefault) reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
       NSInteger locationRow = indexPath.row;
        cell.textLabel.text = [appDelegate.nameArray objectAtIndex:locationRow];
     return cell; // error comes here


}
```

Comment: The answer is within the error description. Check your return type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return type of your function is wrong. It should return `UITableViewCell*` and not `UITableView*`

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableview:(UITableView *)tableview cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

you  are giving the return type as `UITableView` but it expected `UITableViewCell` so you have to change like below

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableview : (UITableView *)tableview cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableview dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) 
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    NSInteger locationRow = indexPath.row;
    cell.textLabel.text = [appDelegate.nameArray objectAtIndex:locationRow];
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check your return type. Because your are returning `UITableViewCell` but your return  type is `UITableView`. For more info see this line in your code.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableview : (UITableView *)tableview cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it more easy, do not create cell inside cellForRowAtIndexPath method, instead use this code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.table registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"MyCell" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"MyCellIdentifier"];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"MyCellIdentifier";
    MyCell *cell = (MyCell*)[self.table dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Setup cell here

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I still got this warning. I m using HVtable as a third party tool

-(TableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath isExpanded:(BOOL)isExpanded {

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MYCELLUP";

UpcomingTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;


NSArray *cellSubs = cell.contentView.subviews;
if (isExpanded){
    [self tableView:tbView expandCell:cell withIndexPath:indexPath];
}
else{
    [self removeExpendedContent:cellSubs];

}

 if(ary_up_trp_typ.count >= 1){

    cell.img_blk_plane.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"page4_09.png"];
    cell.img_day.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"page4_09.png"];


    cell.lbl_up_trp_typ.text = [ary_up_trp_typ objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.lbl_up_dt_to_frm.text = [ary_up_dt_to_frm objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.lbl_up_ct_st.text = [ary_up_ct_st objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.lbl_up_day.text = [ary_up_day objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

}

return cell;
```

}